# Acceptable file formats to import for uv mapping and displacement

Tags: modifiers, uv

Is it possible to import an .obj file, map a .jpg photo to one of the surfaces and displace it only on that surface.  If not an obj file would any other work?

New at this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can .. (this is a monkey I found, and imported as an `.obj` file).. there are a couple of things you might want to do.

- Maybe remap the region you're interested in displacing, to a new UV of your own
- Maybe make a vertex-group from that area, to isolate the displacement to it

[image]

Here, a *Displace* modifier is used, sourcing the UV Map, and aimed at the vertex-group. The subdivision is bumped up for rendering in this example.. these options would all depend on your case:

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

A `.jpg` may not be the best choice of image-format, since it will contain compression artefacts, and won't be in the right color-space to map a displacement linearly.

Again, that may or may not matter in your case.

Comment: Switching Cycles to experimental and enabling adaptive subdivision in the subdiv modifier is a great way to reduce 'stairs'

Comment: Ahh.. I didn't think of that  for displacement in geometry.. of course... :) I suspect this may be for printing anyway.. so that's moot.

Comment: Thanks.  I will work on making an new vertex group.  What photo formats would you recommend.  Essentially I have a 1 foot square surface with a 1/2 inch raised border I made in Freecad.  I want to place a photo within the frame and raise the texture a bit for cnc machining.

Comment: Hi, @Rworks .. it kind of depends where the image comes from.. you would want to wind up with a relatively high bit-depth, or float. linear image. If you're rendering your image from Blender, then EXR half-float, lossless, would be a way to go that is definitely linear..you won't get tangled up in color-space conversions.. but I don't know where your image comes from.

Comment: Image came from photo loaded into "texture from image".

Comment: @Rworks .. hehe.. I mean the _origin_ of the photo .. is it already a .jpg?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  Your a bit ahead of me but I am trying to learn more about "groups" and mapping in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Rworks np.. we're here to help, if we can. To avoid extended commentary, I'm going to move this exchange to our not-so-great chat system. ...  '@' a name to raise a notification.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146415/discussion-on-answer-by-robin-betts-acceptable-file-formats-to-import-for-uv-map); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.